# Laravel Socialite : Login With LinkedIn Gives Error on Cancle Button

Tags: php, laravel, linkedin-api, laravel-socialite

I have followed below link to provide `Login With LinkedIn` in my laravel app.

https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-login-with-linkedin-using-socialite-packageexample.html

All Working fine , I am successfully able to login with likedin .

But problem is when user first time click button Login With Linked on my website , it redirect to linkedIn Page show Dialog with Ok and Cancle button and now if user click on cancle button then its shows below error

[image]

browser url is :

> http://www.mywebsite.com/auth/linkedin/callback?error=user_cancelled_login&error_description=The+user+cancelled+LinkedIn+login&state=NSlF7oA3yFRLCoRi5BARhbVrWwK8b02Mg54Jw5cg

I want when user click on cancle button , it simply redirect to home page of my website .

On LinkedIn Developer Console I have added below url :

**OAuth 2.0**

Authorized Redirect URLs:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/auth/linkedin/callback
```

**OAuth 1.0a**

Default "Accept" Redirect URL:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/auth/linkedin
```

Default "Cancel" Redirect URL:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/
```

please help me to solve out this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this:

In Contoller method withch is called for `http://www.mywebsite.com/auth/linkedin/callback`

```
if($request->has('error')){
 return redirect()
             ->to('admin/login')
             ->withErrors("Access Denied");
}
```

Comment: Thankyou , AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd for giving a patch.

Comment: @SaurabhMistry: Glad to help